# htaccess - How are htaccess files applied to subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^Catalog/Custom_Pages/([^\.]+)\.html$  http://www.domain.com/New/Catalog/Custom_Pages/Custom_Pages_Main.php?cp=$1 [R]
```

The directory structure is domain.com/New/Catalog/

If I omit 'Catalog' at the front of the RewriteRule then the URL is not rewritten. The htaccess file is in the 'New' directory. So does the htaccess for 'New' only apply to its subdirectories or should it apply to all the subdirectories such that 'Catalog' could be omitted? Is this probably a server setting?

Comment: you should give examples of url you want and url you don't want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If .htaccess file is in `/New/` folder, then it will apply for this folder and all subfolders but all URL paths in `RewriteRule` directives will be **relative** to `/New/` folder.

If you want to omit `Catalog/` part from RewriteRule pattern, then try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule Custom_Pages/([^\.]+)\.html$  http://www.domain.com/New/Catalog/Custom_Pages/Custom_Pages_Main.php?cp=$1 [R]
```

Your current pattern clearly says "URL should start with Catalog" (check regex manual what `^` means).

The above rule can then be applied to `Catalog/Custom_Pages/something.html` as well as to `Pink-Kitten/Custom_Pages/something.html`.

Comment: Ok so the carot was causing it. So everything before a carot is the base directory where the htaccess is located. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern will be matched to url of the page, from the directory, so for exemple :

```
http://www.domain.com/New/Catalog/Custom_Pages/test.html
```

From the directory /New the path to the page is :

```
Catalog/Custom_Pages/test.html
```

Then if the regexp pattern matchs `Catalog/Custom_Pages/test.html` the rule will apply, otherway it will not be applied.

ps : if there is a .htaccess in `Catalog` or `Custom_Pages` their rules will be tested first.